# C++: Semantics for read-only and write-only versions of a class

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

In my program, I have a data structure called `Foo`. One part of the program constructs `Foo` from a set of parameters and so need access to mutative methods. Another part of the program will only read from `Foo` and so should not have access to mutative methods.

What is the best way to accomplish this, or am I taking the wrong view of how classes should work? I've used this way in the past:

```
class FooR {
public:
    int read() { return x; }
protected:
    int x;
};

class FooRW : public FooR {
    void mutate(int nx) { x = nx; }
};
```

But this way feels like you're abusing inheritance and I think it  might cause confusion to have two very similarly named classes in two parts of the program. Are there better ways? Can you use `const` in some tricky way?

**EDIT:** 
@jens pointed out that using `const` references in the read-only part of the program should work, which made me realize it's important to know that my data structure is actually a tree, something like:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void splitNode();
    Foo *getChild(int n) const; // const Foo?
private:
    Foo *children[2];
};
```

Is there a way of forcing a `const Foo` to return only `const` references to its children?

Comment: This looks like an anti-pattern if I've ever seen one.

Comment: Why not just give `const Foo` to the part that is read-only, and `Foo` to the part that isn't?

Comment: You could also have a factory that has `friend` permissions if you only need to write on creation. The builder pattern may work too, although I think that's a type of factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parts of your program which do not need to change the object should just usr const references, and mark the non-mutating member functions as const.

```
class FooR {
public:
    int read() const { return x; }
    void mutate(int nx) { x = nx; }
private:
    int x;
};

void f1(FooR const& obj)
{
    int x = obj.read();
    // cannot use obj.mutate(x+1);
}
void mutatingFunction(FooR&);
```

You could do the construction in a factory or build, and return a `std::unique_ptr<FooR const>` or a `std::shared_ptr<FooR const>` to prevent anybody else from using the mutating interface.

The same approach works for the tree. Declare a const-overload returning `Foo const*`, and a non-const overload returning a non-const pointer. The later one cannot be used from const references.

```
class Foo {
public:
    void splitNode();
    Foo const* getChild(int n) const;
    Foo* getChild(int n); 
private:
    Foo *children[2];
};
```

Comment: I like the const idea! However it made me realize I need to explain more about `Foo` because I realized there may be a problem with the `const` approach, I've edited my post.